# How can I run clean-up offline in Team City?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Our Team City server got to a state when nothing works including the `Start clean-up now' button, because the internal database size is >900MB. Yes, we are still trying to get a proper external database... In the meantime is there a way to shut down Team City and run the clean-up manually from the command line? How can we recover from this state otherwise?

We are running version 8.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what do you want to clean up : artefacts, directory etc.

I ran into the same issues when I setup teamcity initially. I used to go into the agent work directories , figure out the directories taking the max space and run `rm -rf` on the agent work directories (the ones with the alphanumeric sha id) .

One good thing about our setup is that we named all our checkout directories , so it was very easy to identify multiple runs for the same build, so I used to delete every checkout build except the latest one.

In case you have artefact dependencies, I would advise you not to do this process